# Angular 6 Children/Parent Communication

Tags: html, angular, typescript, parent, children

I'm having a problem replace a div in the parent component to contain children component. (I want something like AJAX but with angular)
For example I have this html parent and children:

```html
parent-component.html

<div class="col-md-12">
  <h1>{{parent.name}}</h1>
  <p> this is the parent component div. click the link below to replace this div with the children div</p>
  <a>Click here</a>
  <children></children>
</div>



children-component.html

<div class="col-md-12">
  <h1>{{parent.children.name}}</h1>
  <p> this is the children div </p>
</div>
```

So what I basically want is if we click in the link, the whole div in the parent component file is replaced with the div in the children (and we go to a children route /parent/:id/children/:id)

**EDIT: I'll explain why I need it so I'll be clear.**
I have course component. every course contains array of segments. every segments contains type and data attribute. if type = video, the data type is filed with url. if the type is quiz, data is empty. also, every segment has array of questions. the array is empty if the type is video.

when I click on a quiz link, I want a page which have a 'Start Quiz' link that when I click on it, the whole div is replaced with list of questions (the child component).

interfaces and relations:

```js
export interface ICourse {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  autor: string;
  segments: ISegment[];
}

export interface ISegment {
  id: number;
  unit_id: number;
  unit_title: string;
  name: string;
  type: string;
  data: string;
  questions: IQuestion[];
}

export interface IQuestion {
  id: number;
  question: string;
  answer1: string;
  answer2: string;
  answer3: string;
  answer4: string;
  correct: number;
}
```

this is the html file of the 'parent' (the child component is course-quiz)

```html
  <div class="row content" *ngIf="course">
    <!-- Side nav-bar -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <!-- Image Logo -->
      <div id="head_sidebar">
        <img src="./assets/images/lg-white.png" class="d-inline-block align-top logo" alt="" routerLink="/courses" style="outline: none">
        <h3>{{course.title}}</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12 sidenav">
        <!-- Menu elemets -->
        <div class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" *ngFor="let unit of course.segments | groupBy: 'unit_title'; let i = index">
          <h6 class="course_play_title">Unit {{ i+1 }}: {{ unit.key }} </h6>
          <ul>
            <li class="course_play_item"  *ngFor="let lesson of unit.value">
              <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/courses/{{course.id}}/segments/{{lesson.id}}" (click)=getCurrentSegment(lesson.id)>{{lesson.name}} </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Body -->
    <div class="col-md-9 no-gutters" *ngIf="currentSegment">
      <!-- Video Div -->
      <div class="col-md-12 course_play_body text-center" *ngIf="currentSegment.segment_type === 'Video'">
        <h1>{{currentSegment.name}}</h1>
        <p class="small-text" *ngIf="course.segments?.length > 0">lesson {{currentSegment.id}} of {{course.segments?.length}}</p>
        <hr>
        <iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" [src]='currentSegment.data | safe'></iframe>
      </div>

      <!-- Quiz Div -->
      <div class="col-md-12 course_play_body text-center" *ngIf="currentSegment.segment_type === 'Quiz'">
        <h1>{{currentSegment.name}}</h1>
        <p class="text-left"> Now that you've finished this unit, It's time to take a short quiz and see what you learned so far!
            You'll need to choose one out of four answers which you think is correct.
            After you've finished the quiz, you'll get your grade. feel free to re-take this quiz as much as you like.
            Good Luck!
        </p>
        <p class="big-text" *ngIf="currentSegment.questions?.lenght > 0"> {{currentSegment.questions?.lenght}} questions </p>
        <a><h4>Start Quiz</h4></a>
        <quiz-course></quiz-course>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

**routing:**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { CourseListComponent } from './courses/course-list/course-list.component';
import { CourseDetailComponent } from './courses/course-detail/course-detail.component';
import { CoursePlayComponent } from './courses/course-play/course-play.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { CourseQuizComponent } from './courses/course-play/course-quiz/course-quiz.component';


// Routing array - set routes to each html page
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/courses', pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' },
  { path: 'courses', component: CourseListComponent,  pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' },
  { path: 'courses/:id', component: CourseDetailComponent, pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' },
  { path: 'courses/:id/segments/:id', component: CoursePlayComponent, pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    children: [{ path: 'questions/:id', component: CourseQuizComponent }]
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent, pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {  }
```

Comment: what the purpose and logic of doing this?

Comment: Hi, you attention is after click you need to route into the url '/parent/:id/children/:id ' in this page you want to show '<h1>{{parent.children.name}}</h1>' right ?

Comment: It looks to me that you can use *ngIf="showChildren" and a flag or better use the route.naviage(...) and handle this route in a new component. even better to read.

Comment: Use `input` and `output`s

Comment: I added my situation and why I need it. It's a little complicated so I didn't mention in

Comment: how do I use input and output for this? I want to replace a div and not just add to an exist div information

Comment: btw: use [routerLink] with [ ]

Comment: @Alexander is pointing towards right solution

Comment: @Alexander can you be more specific? how do I use it?

Answer (score 0):

you should configure route for your child component in app module like this

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'courses/:courseid/:lessonId', component: desire component },
];
```

In imports array import it as:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
```

finally in HTML

```
 <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/courses',course.id,lesson.id]">{{lesson.name}} </a>
```

Moreover why are you using click event as well as router link on same anchor tag?

*Note: I have not tested the code I am just giving an example*

Comment: I did but it's not working. I added now my routing array

Comment: have you imported router module also?

Comment: yes and in other components it's working, just in this it's not, it's duplicate the url

Comment: try to resolve url issue I jsut gave an quick example

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty, you can fix it like this:

```
<a *ngIf="!showQuiz" (click)="showQuiz = true"><h4>Start Quiz</h4></a>
<quiz-course *ngIf="showQuiz" [questions]="currentSegment?.questions"></quiz-course>
```

you have to set an @Input() questions; in your child component.

---

Additional, you can use

```
route: ActivatedRoute,
```

to set the currentSegment on loading.

Comment: just true or false. (It should be false on load)
sorry for the name, ich will changen it to showQuiz

Comment: I used your code but now I have a problem that the route isn't changing and when I try to enter /courses/3/segments/7/questions/1 it's not showing